# PowerShell send email using CSV Column Provided email

Tags: powershell, csv

CSV File format header:

```
Request ID  Requester Name  Binary  Template    Serial Number   Certificate Effective Date  Certificate Expiration Date Issued Country.Region   Issued Organization Issued Organization Unit    Issued Common Name  Issued City Issued State    Issued Email Address
```

I have the following code where I am trying to send email using the email provided in the CSV 'Issued Email Address' where Issued Email and Serial Number are in the same row. My code sends email out to each Issued email address but in the body of the message, its all the information for all Issued email users.

```
   Param(
    [Int]$Months = $null,
    [Int]$Days = $null,
    [switch]$noMail = $false
)
# --------------------------------------------------
#functions

Function Send-CertificateList
{
    $FromAddress = 'myemail@email.com'
    $ToAddress = $ToAddress
    $MessageSubject = "Certificate expiration reminder from $env:COMPUTERNAME.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"
    $SendingServer = 'smtp.SendingServer.com'
    $port = '587'

    $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $FromAddress, $ToAddress, $MessageSubject, $mailbody -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $SMTPMessage.IsBodyHTML = $true
    $SMTPMessage.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High
    $SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $SendingServer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if(Test-Connection -Cn $SendingServer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet){
        $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
    }else{
        Write-Host 'No connection to SMTP server. Failed to send email!'
        Write-Output 'No connection to SMTP server. Failed to send email!' | Out-File $mailstatus -Append
    }
}

# --------------------------------------------------

#HTML Style
$style = "<style>body{font-family:`"Calibri`",`"sans-serif`"; font-size: 14px;}"
$style = $style + "@font-face
    {font-family:`"Cambria Math`";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}"
$style = $style + "table{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}"
$style = $style + "th{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "td{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + ".crtsn{font-weight: bold; color: blue; }"
$style = $style + ".crtexp{font-weight: bold; color: red; }"
$style = $style + ".crtcn{font-weight: bold; color: orange; }"
$style = $style + "</style>"

# --------------------------------------------------
#variables
$strDate = get-date -format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss
#$exportFileName = "certs_" + $strDate + ".csv"
$now = Get-Date
$nowm = $now.Month
$nowy = $now.Year
$mailbody = @()
$expirymy = @()
$table = @()
$ToAddress = @()

# --------------------------------------------------
#variables

#export certificates to CSV
#certutil.exe -view csv > $exportFileName
$a = Import-Csv .\csv_file.csv 
#Import certificates from CSV
$importexp = $a | Select-Object 'Certificate Expiration Date'
$importall = $a | Where-Object {$_.'Serial Number' -notcontains 'EMPTY'} | Where-Object {$_.'Certificate Expiration Date' -like "*.$arg0*"} | Where-Object {$_.'Issued Email Address' -notcontains 'EMPTY'} | Select-Object -Property 'Request ID','Serial Number','Requester Name','Certificate Expiration Date','Request Common Name','Request Disposition', 'Issued Email Address'

#build email body in HTML
$mailbody += '<html><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' + $style + '</head><body>'
$mailbody += "These certificates will expire soon:<br />"

#convert dates and extract month and year
foreach($i in $importall){
   $expiry = Get-Date $i.'Certificate Expiration Date' -Format 'M.d.yyyy HH:mm'
   $expirymy += Get-Date $expiry | Select-Object Month, Year
}

#cycle through array and search for matching cetificates
for($i=0;$i -lt $expirymy.Count;$i++){
    if(($expirymy[$i].Month -gt $nowm)){
        if((($expirymy[$i].Month - $nowm) -le $Months) -and (($expirymy[$i].Year - $nowy) -eq '0')){
            Write-Host 'Certificate ID:' $importall[$i].'Request ID' 'with Serial Number:' $importall[$i].'Serial Number' 'will expire in ' -NoNewline; Write-Host ($expirymy[$i].Month - $nowm) 'months!'-ForegroundColor Red            
            Write-Host 'Email:' $importall[$i].'Issued Email Address'
            Write-Host 'Please don`t forget to renew this certificate before expiration date: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host $importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date' -ForegroundColor Red "`n"

            $ToAddress = $importall[$i].'Issued Email Address'
            $mailbody += '<p>'
            $mailbody += 'Certificate ID: ' + $importall[$i].'Request ID' + ' with Serial Number: <span class="crtsn"">' + $importall[$i].'Serial Number' + '</span> will expire in <span class="crtexp">' + ($expirymy[$i].Month - $nowm) + ' months!</span>'+"<br />"
            $mailbody += 'This certificate has Common Name: <span class="crtcn">' + $importall[$i].'Issued Common Name' + "</span><br />"
            $mailbody += $importall[$i].'Issued Email Address'
            $mailbody += 'Please don`t forget to renew this certificate before expiration date: <span class="crtexp">' + $importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date'+"</span>"
            $mailbody += '</p>'
            $table += $importall[$i] | Sort-Object 'Certificate Expiration Date' | Select-Object -Property 'Request ID','Serial Number','Requester Name','Certificate Expiration Date','Issued Common Name', 'Issued Email Address'
            Write-Host $table
        }
    }
}

$mailbody += '<p><table>'
$mailbody += '<th>Request ID</th><th>Serial Number</th><th>Requester Name</th><th>Issued CN</th><th>Expiration date</th><th>Email</th>'

foreach($row in $table){
    $mailbody += "<tr><td>" + $row.'Request ID' + "</td><td>" + $row.'Serial Number' + "</td><td>" + $row.'Requester Name' + "</td><td>" + $row.'Issued Common Name' + "</td><td>" + $row.'Certificate Expiration Date' + "</td> <td>" + $row.'Issued Email Address' + "</td></tr>"
    $ToAddress = $row.'Issued Email Address'
}

$mailbody += '</table></p>'
$mailbody += '</body>'
$mailbody += '</html>'
#$ToAddress = $ToAddress
foreach($row in $table){
    $ToAddress = $row.'Issued Email Address'
    Write-Host $ToAddress
    if(($table.Count -gt '0') -and (!$noMail)){
        Send-CertificateList
}
}
```

Comment: what problem you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I have no way of easily testing this, but it seems to me that there is no need to have `foreach ($i in $ImportAll)` and `for ($i=0;$i -lt $expirymy.Count;$i++)`. As far as I can tell everything can be done in your `foreach` loop. Also month and year can be added to each object as properties.

```
foreach($Entry in $Importall)
{
   $expiry = Get-Date $i.'Certificate Expiration Date' 
   $Entry | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Month -Value $expiry.Month
   $Entry | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name year -Value $expiry.Year


    #cycle through array and search for matching cetificates
    if(($Entry.Month -gt $nowm)){
        if((($Entry.Month - $nowm) -le $Months) -and (($Entry.Year - $nowy) -eq '0')){
            Write-Host 'Certificate ID:' $Entry.'Request ID' 'with Serial Number:' $Entry.'Serial Number' 'will expire in ' -NoNewline; Write-Host ($Entry.Month - $nowm) 'months!'-ForegroundColor Red            
            Write-Host 'Email:' $Entry.'Issued Email Address'
            Write-Host 'Please don`t forget to renew this certificate before expiration date: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host $Entry.'Certificate Expiration Date' -ForegroundColor Red "`n"

            $ToAddress = $Entry.'Issued Email Address'
            $mailbody += '<p>'
            $mailbody += 'Certificate ID: ' + $Entry.'Request ID' + ' with Serial Number: <span class="crtsn"">' + $Entry.'Serial Number' + '</span> will expire in <span class="crtexp">' + ($Entry.Month - $nowm) + ' months!</span>'+"<br />"
            $mailbody += 'This certificate has Common Name: <span class="crtcn">' + $Entry.'Issued Common Name' + "</span><br />"
            $mailbody += $Entry.'Issued Email Address'
            $mailbody += 'Please don`t forget to renew this certificate before expiration date: <span class="crtexp">' + $Entry.'Certificate Expiration Date'+"</span>"
            $mailbody += '</p>'
            $table += $Entry | Sort-Object 'Certificate Expiration Date' | Select-Object -Property 'Request ID','Serial Number','Requester Name','Certificate Expiration Date','Issued Common Name', 'Issued Email Address'
            Write-Host $table
        }
    }
}
```